# restrict lambda to use only some data centres?

Tags: aws-lambda

I’m researching my options to publish microservices under AWS lambda. As we will be billed by the microsecond and memory used, performance of our lambda functions is pretty important.

My DB is Cassandra or other NOSQL distributed on several AWS nodes, on several data centres.

5. **How can I configure lambda to be sure that my lambda function, including DB access, is using a DB node on the same data centre?**

I know that Cassandra drivers will redirect intelligently queries to the nearest DB node, but what I need is to the restrict lambda execution to just nodes on the same data centres where I have some DB node.

Comment: *"As we will be billed by the microsecond and memory used"*  Note that neither of these assertions is very accurate.  Function invocations are billed in 100 *millisecond* increments, and based on memory available, not used.  Additionally, you are the term "data centre" has no defined meaning, here -- are you referring to running in specific availability zones, or specific regions?

Comment: I grant you is not very accurate, but optimize time and memory is important, this is my point. By data centre I mean, I just want my lambda function querying and downloading database data from same physical location, to prevent internet wide data transfers

Answer (score 2):

1. You can configure or create a lambda role using IAM roles which will have access to only a specific aws resource (you can be restrictive or open on access control by specifying that in the policies).
2. Then assign that role to your lambda in a VPC or default VPC.